# MySql_query insert null not 0

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

**Database:**

> DAlanding  int(11) Ja NULL

```
$DAlanding = $_POST['DAlanding '];

if ($DAlanding =="")
{
    $DAlanding =NULL;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO cardex (DAlanding) VALUES('$DAlanding')";
```

But now i need it for a date to:

> DAdate  date Ja NULL

```
$DAdate  = $_POST['DAdate '];

if ($DAdate  =="")
{
    $DAdate  = 'NULL';
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO cardex (DAdate) VALUES('$DAdate')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the datatype as varchar or char. if we used int its automatically assigned the 0 to corresponding field.

Comment: Useing 
if ($PPAlanding==""){ $PPAlanding='NULL';}
And in my Database changed into varchar it help.

So i changed my DB to varchar
En add ''

Comment: But do you have the anser for a date?

Comment: we cannot fix for date field. it should assigned 0000-00-00 like this

Answer (score 1):

In order to insert `NULL` you need to pass it without quotes.

```
$DAlanding = isset($_POST['DAlanding']) && $_POST['DAlanding'] != '' ? "'" . $_POST['DAlanding'] . "'" : 'NULL';

$sql = "INSERT INTO cardex (DAlanding) VALUES($DAlanding)";
```

You should lookup SQL Injection because you are inserting raw user input, creating a vulnerability.

Comment: Echo out `$sql` and show us what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Make NULL as string "NULL". Then SQL will be correct.

```
 if ($DAlanding =="")
    {
        $DAlanding ="NULL";
    }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO cardex (DAlanding) VALUES($DAlanding)";
```

Comment: Doesnt help all ready have tryed.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that you don't get an error attempting to insert a `STRING` value into `int` column.
Usually you omit the column that you don't want to insert anything into

Comment: I can just insert a value like 5 or something but i want if there is no input there will be NULL and not the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($DAdate  =="")
{
    $DAlanding= NULL;
}
else{
    $DAlanding= "'".$DAdate."'";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO cardex (DAlanding) VALUES($DAlanding)";
```

remove ' before and after $DAlanding

Comment: I think when the value is null you are right. but when i have a value i get an error.

Comment: i've edited my sol. check now